# How to find preemption time of processes in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, real-time, rtos, preemption

I am trying to programmatically find the preemption time between two processes on my Ubuntu laptop. I am trying to implement the method mentioned in this research paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8441042. This paper calculates preemption time of processes in Vxworks OS. I am trying to do the exact same thing on my Ubuntu system.

As described in this paper, I created two processes (C programs with infinite loop) of different priorities using `nice` command. The lower priority task is run immediately (at time-stamp t1), while the higher priority task is run after a gap of 10 microseconds (at time-stamp t2). Then the preemption time should be t2-t1-10 microseconds. Both the processes run on the same processor using the `taskset` command. `chrt` command is used to set the scheduler to FIFO.

I cannot think of a better approach to implement the ideas of the above research paper on my Ubuntu system. I am also not sure that the above approach is foolproof. There are some obvious problems such as the processes that I have created may get preempted by some other higher priority tasks or the processes may get blocked due to some reason.

So, if there is a better way to go about calculating preemption time programmatically kindly please tell me some approach or point me to resources where I can learn about them. Thanks.

Comment: Without showing your test code rather then merely _describing_ it it is hard to tell.  What results did you get?  It is most probably a pointless exercise; Linux is not a real-time operating system.  Even if you are successful in taking a measurement, it will be widely variable and with no guarantees because the Linux scheduler is not _deterministic_ - especially with the default round-robin scheduler.  Also VxWorks tasks are _threads_ not _processes_.  Context switching a process is a "heavyweight" switch, so you are perhaps not comparing like for like.

Comment: Perhaps https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/ would be of interest.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am now trying to work with threads instead. The blog you shared is very helpful. Many thanks!